# Why does my WebView not load the new content?

Tags: ios, url, webview, request

I have a method that loads the content in my WebView:

```
-(void)loadContent:(NSURLRequest *)requestObj{
    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    webView.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"LOAD WEBSITE!!!");  
}
```

when I first call it like this:

```
[self loadContent:requestObj];
```

it works fine! But when I call it again for a new URL, it does not work.

I have readed that it will help to call the following before loading the new URL:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.open();document.close()"];
```

But it doesn't change the result. Does anyone know how to handle this? Please be patient with me, I'm new in the iOS-world.

Ok i find out, my WebView is Null, but why? I call it from the ViewController and it has to be there. Does someone know how to handle this?

UPDATE: It is not Null any more cause i do this:

```
if(!webView)
{
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
}
```

But it does not change the content when i do this: `[webView loadRequest:requestObj];`

Comment: where are you calling it from? could the webview be nil? this code would work. remember the webview needs the main  thread, so if you block that, it wont load/show.

Comment: Why are you using `webView.delegate = self` in that method? Usually one would place that line in viewDidLoad

Comment: @Daij-Djan I call it from AppDelegate.m in clickedButtonAtIndex

Comment: @AceLegend i dont place it in viewDidLoad cause i need my own methode to fill it with new URL´s

Comment: But why does that mean you shouldn't set the delegate. Are you saying you want to block other URLS? You want to control them or something?

Comment: Do you have a `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` ? That's a way to see if your webview is even thinking about loading.

Comment: @Daij-Djan Damn you are right! It is nil. But i dont know why. :)

Comment: @AceLegend No i just want to have 1 webView and this webView has to change the website when the user push a button from alertView.

Comment: Well. Why does that stop you from setting the delegate before? When they press the button you simply need to have an action that loads the URL. Anyway, I don't think this has anything to do with your problem. Good luck!

Comment: @AceLegend Now i know what you mean! But like you say it does not help me with my problem. :(

Comment: what do you do right before and right after calling this?

Comment: @Daij-Djan Before i make a NSURLRequest and after i try following to get the new website: [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.open();document.close()"];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

Comment: How did you define webView? Is it a property/ ivar/ outlet? Where is it initialized?

Comment: @DiederikHoogenboom I just added it with Drag & Drop in MainStoryBoard and in viewDidLoad i say: webView.delegate = self;[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try reloading the view like self  reload.nameOfTheView

Comment: or try to load it by calling in the viewDidLoad method itself

Comment: Nice that works. But now i have a problem with getter and setter. I cant set in AppDelegat. Do you have a tutorial for getter and setter? Please! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your webview created in a nib? If so, it may not be connected.

Comment: No, I created it with MainStoryBoard and filled it first in viewDidLoad(). And now i want to have new content in it and call my loadContent(),wish is in ViewController, from AppDelegate. But it is Null now. :(

Comment: So your view controller has a webView ivar that you assign in viewDidLoad, right? Did you declare the webView variable as weak?

Comment: ok i have it..its not more null, but it does not change the content when i request new URL.

Comment: Maybe it is a caching issue. What if you set the cachePolicy of the NSURLRequest to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData?

Answer (score 0):

http://sweng.epfl.ch/tutorials/getting-started-with-ios-developement-xcode-and-objective-c

you can go through the above link and find a step by step procedure

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2712/using-properties-in-objective-c-tutorial

you can download a sample code from the above link.